# What is the difference between dp and dip?

Tags: android, android-layout, screen-resolution

I am currently using following image view -

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/flag"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        />
```

but i am a little confused about

**what to use `dp` or `dip`?**

so that it changes from device to device say it should manage screen dimensions like for `320 x 640` Or is there anything else to manage it

thanks in advance

Comment: pls read http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: dp = dip .....please take a look [difference-between-px-dp-dip-and-sp-in-android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-between-px-dp-dip-and-sp-in-android)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-between-px-dp-dip-and-sp-in-android

Comment: doth are same.Do some googling.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's NO DIFFERENCE. dip and dp are the very same thing.

Comment: Just a note for those stumbling across this in the future: The difference, that dp is more consistent with sp, is stated directly in the documentation. This can result in slight alteration of the size depending on the specific density of the device. The original answer disregards this detail.